# Selenium 2 StaleElementReferenceException When Using DropDownList with AutoPostBack With InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2 to test an asp.net web forms page using the InternetExplorerDriver and am encountering a StaleElementReferenceException. The page contains a (auto-postback) drop down list, which I am selecting different values from.

Example code:

Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="one"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="two"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

(The code-behind file contains nothing more than the Visual Studio auto-created stuff.)

Test fixture code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace IntegrationTests
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class WebForm1TestFixture
  {
    [Test]
    public void ShouldSelectItemOneThenItemTwo()
    {
      IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); // Using ChromeDriver causes test to pass...
      driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/<my-virtual-directory-name>/WebForm1.aspx");
      IWebElement list = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddl"));
      IWebElement itemOne = list.FindElement(By.XPath("option[1]"));
      itemOne.Select();
      list = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddl"));
      IWebElement itemTwo = list.FindElement(By.XPath("option[2]"));
      itemTwo.Select();
      list = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddl"));
      itemOne = list.FindElement(By.XPath("option[1]"));// This line causes the StaleElementReferenceException to occur
      itemOne.Select();

      // Some assertion would go here
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in e:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\remote\client\src\csharp\webdriver-remote-client\RemoteWebDriver.cs: line 883
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(DriverCommand driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in e:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\remote\client\src\csharp\webdriver-remote-client\RemoteWebDriver.cs: line 727
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.FindElement(String mechanism, String value) in e:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\remote\client\src\csharp\webdriver-remote-client\RemoteWebElement.cs: line 570
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.FindElementByXPath(String xpath) in e:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\remote\client\src\csharp\webdriver-remote-client\RemoteWebElement.cs: line 458
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClasse.<XPath>b__c(ISearchContext context) in e:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\common\src\csharp\webdriver-common\By.cs: line 119
at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context) in e:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\common\src\csharp\webdriver-common\By.cs: line 227
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.FindElement(By by) in e:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\remote\client\src\csharp\webdriver-remote-client\RemoteWebElement.cs: line 267
at IntegrationTests.WebForm1TestFixture.ShouldSelectItemOneThenItemTwo() in WebForm1TestFixture.cs: line 25
```

If I change the test to use a ChromeDriver then the test passes. It seems to me like this means it is either a problem with the InternetExplorerDriver or the Internet Explorer browser itself. Does anybody know which and if there's anything I can do to get round this (the site will be used in IE by the end users, so changing browsers isn't possible, unfortunately)?

---

**EDIT:** The current work-around that I am using is to put a `Thread.Sleep()` after the list has been selected; this works but obviously isn't an ideal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the pattern I ended up implementing.

After each `item*.Select()` I've implemented a wait:

```
IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new MyCustomWebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(driver => <some-condition-to-wait-for>);
```

Where <some-condition-to-wait-for> is a way of determining that the item selection has finished (for example, by checking that another control on the page has been updated, e.g.

```
wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Id("someLabelId")).Text == "expectedValue")`.
```

`MyCustomWebDriverWait` is a class that implements `IWait<IWebDriver>` and is almost identical to the [WebDriverWait](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/src/WebDriver.Support/UI/WebDriverWait.cs) class, only it catches `StaleElementReferenceException` as well as `NotFoundException` (which meant changing the type of `lastException` from `NotFoundException` to `WebDriverException`.

You can read how I was pointed in this direction by Daniel Wagner-Hall on the Selenium-users google group [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/selenium-users/u7HEjD3NO5Q/discussion).

Comment: So are you using this for every single call to `FindElement`?

Comment: @VictorioBerra Umm, I can't remember - this was a long time ago, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The list element could be changing in the DOM due to the autopostback.
Try refinding the list element each time you select an option.  E.g.

```
IWebElement itemOne = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddl")).FindElement(By.XPath("option[1]"));
  itemOne.Select();
  IWebElement itemTwo = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddl")).FindElement(By.XPath("option[1]"));
  itemTwo.Select();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am already doing that in the code sample above...(unless I am going mad, which is not entirely unlikely)

Answer (score 0):

I found calling `driver.refresh()` after going to the page that it worked fine, my code is:

```
        Pages.Login.Goto();
        Browser.Refresh(); <-- refresh the webdriver after going to the page
        Pages.Login.LogInAsRegularUser();
```