# How and when to implement refreshed(ExpectedCondition<T> condition) of Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was going through methods of `ExpectedCondtions` class and found one method: [refreshed](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#refreshed(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition))

I can understand that the method can be used when you get `StaleElementReferenceException` and you want to retrieve that element again and this way to avoid `StaleElementReferenceException`

My above understanding might not be correct hence I want to confirm:

1. When `refreshed` should be used?
2. What should be the code for `something` part of following code:

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(**something**));`

Can someone please explain this with an example?

Comment: Very good question! I would like to see a wise answer of this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the source:

> Wrapper for a condition, which allows for elements to update by redrawing.
> This works around the problem of conditions which have two parts: find an
> element and then check for some condition on it. For these conditions it is
> possible that an element is located and then subsequently it is redrawn on
> the client. When this happens a {@link StaleElementReferenceException} is
> thrown when the second part of the condition is checked.

So basically, this is a method that waits until a DOM manipulation is finished on an object.

Typically, when you do `driver.findElement`  that object represents what the object is.

When the DOM has manipulated, and say after clicking a button, adds a class to that element.  If you try to perform an action on said element, it will throw `StaleElementReferenceException`  since now the `WebElement` returned now does not represent the updated element.

You'll use `refreshed` when you expect DOM manipulation to occur, and you want to wait until it's done being manipulated in the DOM.

#### Example:

```
<body>
  <button id="myBtn" class="" onmouseover="this.class = \"hovered\";" />
</body>

// pseudo-code
1. WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("myBtn")); // right now, if you read the Class, it will return ""
2. button.hoverOver(); // now the class will be "hovered"
3. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(button));
4. button = driver.findElement(By.id("myBtn")); // by this point, the DOM manipulation should have finished since we used refreshed.
5. button.getClass();  // will now == "hovered"
```

*Note that if you perform say a `button.click()` at line #3, it will throw a StaleReferenceException since the DOM has been manipulated at this point.*

In my years of using Selenium, I've never had to use this condition, so I believe that it is an "edge case" situation, that you most likely won't even have to worry about using.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I have been writing selenium tests for a while now and never had to use that. But, can you at least show a high level implementation of that though?

Comment: Appreciate that @ sircapsalot

Comment: According to the documentation here: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html the ExpectedCondition.refreshed() expects another ExpectedCondition, and not a WebElement as in your example.  Could you explain or update your example?  Thanks.

Comment: @sircapsalot the above issue is a common one, whenever a developer uses a 'AutoPostBack="true"' , you do fall in the sort of situation. [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116258/selenium-2-staleelementreferenceexception-when-using-dropdownlist-with-autopostb)

Answer (score 12):

The `refreshed` method has been very helpful for me when trying to access a search result that has been newly refreshed. Trying to wait on the search result by just `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(...)` returns `StaleElementReferenceException`. To work around that, this is the helper method that would wait and retry for a max of 30s for the search element to be refreshed and clickable.

```
public WebElement waitForElementToBeRefreshedAndClickable(WebDriver driver, By by) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(
                    ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)));
}
```

Then to click on the result after searching:

```
waitForElementToBeRefreshedAndClickable(driver, By.cssSelector("css_selector_to_search_result_link")).click();
```

Hope this was helpful for others.

Comment: This is really good, was facing the same with search results.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myBtn"))));
```