# Python + Selenium StaleElement with Loop and Click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have links that I am iterating through, essentially what I am doing is clicking the link and asserting that the new page has the title of the link text on the new page.

It works fine for the first one, until I driver.back() and look for the next link.

I get a StaleElementReference when trying to find the title for the 2nd element. But I cannot re-find it, because it's searching via loop.

```
 flyoutNavLinkItems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".header-desktop div#megamenu .navLinkItem")
    self.assertEqual(len(flyoutNavLinkItems), constant.FLYOUT_CAT_COUNT)

    for item in flyoutNavLinkItems:
        categoryTitle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.navLinkText').text
        print(f'Category Title {categoryTitle}')
        item.click()

        self.assertIn(categoryTitle, driver.title.upper())
        driver.back()
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")` Try using this instead of driver.back()

Comment: Tried:

still 
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: I would need a full code to test, but I suggest putting timer above self.assertIn and after it, also for debug purpose add print statement and see what is it outputing for categoryTitle

Comment: That's all you really need to be honest, flyoutNavlinks is a bunch of anchor tags. Read text, Click first, Compare Text to screen, Go back, do the next. But on the next it breaks. I've tried with timers, but still StaleElementReference because of item in the loop.

Comment: Do you understand what a stale element is?

Comment: Yes, it cannot find the element because the DOM has changed or reloaded. So when the driver.back() happens it cannot find that element anymore, I must manually find it again using driver._____('selector')

Comment: You might want to look at using `ExpectedConditions.refreshed()` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44791057/6205848

Comment: Heya, I tried the explicit waits with webdriver that has EC. Gives same error, StaleReference for any following element that was found before. Has to be found again. Which is a problem in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around via css-selector n-th child and index:

```
for index, item in enumerate(flyoutNavLinkItems):
    print(f'Index {index}')
    selectorToSearch = f'div#megamenu .navLinkItem:nth-of-type({index + 1})'
    item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selectorToSearch)
    categoryTitle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selectorToSearch + ' span.navLinkText').text
    print(f'Category Title {categoryTitle}')
    item.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    self.assertIn(categoryTitle, driver.title.upper())
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(2)
```